# Excel functions for whole columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I was wondering how you would make a function for a whole columns by using other columns in the function. So for example column C = A + B. and this would work for the whole column not matter what the row is. Note: I do know how to select a whole column. :)

EDIT: what i am meaning is that for c3 c4 c5 c6 ect all have the function that the a3+b3 = c3 then a4+b4=c4 and so on and so forth

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Sorry about that, I misunderstood.

All you need is to have the function in the first cell, then you "drag" it down and it will fill for you.

In the screenshot, you can see the function bar, me dragging it and the arrow is to the little box to drag with.

[image]

Comment: See my edit sorry

Comment: @Nicholas - Is that what you meant?

Comment: What's it going to be....